# How would I call a web-service from Google Glass

Tags: google-glass, google-mirror-api

I was exploring Google glass. From the dev guides it is clear that to call web services I need to Mirror Apis. But mirror APIs seems to me a platform that helps inserting cards into Glass timeline from remote location. 
Can Mirror API help me to get the data from some remote server and return a JSON or XML response ? Or Otherwise via Mirror API I need to parse the response and prepare a Card there to push it to Glass Timeline.

Anyone please help me out on this query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neither API, Mirror or GDK, will actually do the work of calling the remote server and getting a response - those are normal things that you should be able to do with the underlying tools they are built on (whatever platform you choose to develop with, if you're using Mirror, or Android if you're using the GDK).

What both APIs support, however, is helping you deliver that information to Glass in the most appropriate way possible.

The Mirror API is good for Glassware that is accessed over the Internet and work with the native timeline operations that Glass provides. The GDK is useful for more immersive or dynamic applications that don't necessarily work with the timeline or the network.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. It cleared all my doubts.

Comment: Check out the following for info on accessing web services from the Mirror API: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563574/can-mirror-api-call-an-external-web-service/21212711#21212711

Answer (score 0):

It's the second one: **Otherwise via Mirror API I need to parse the response and prepare a Card there to push it to Glass Timeline.** .  This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563574/can-mirror-api-call-an-external-web-service) discusses the notion of accessing web services from the Mirror API, but to answer your question, your web server will need to get and parse the XML/JSON data, create a card (using the data) and push it to your Glass device.

Comment: Thanks for this alternative approach.